# How to get a file from the files on my computer to JupyterLab?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am very new to this and struggling with the basics. I have a csv file /home/emily/Downloads/Roger-Federer.csv The textbook says that I need to "extract the file and download it to my current directory" on JupyterLab (I am using Python). What does this mean? How do I do this? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Every running program, including JupyterLab, has a "working directory" which is where it thinks it is on your computer's file system. What exactly this directory is usually depends on how you launched it (e.g., when you run a program from terminal, its working directory is initially the folder your terminal was in when you ran the command, but it's possible for a program to change its own working directory later).

Your file path indicates you're on Linux, so I'd suggest opening a terminal in your JupyterLab and running `pwd` to have it print out its current directory. (You can also run `!pwd` in any open notebook if that's easier.) You should then copy your CSV file to that directory.

If you do that, then from your Python code, you can just open the file locally, like `open('Roger-Federer.csv')` or `pandas.read_csv('Roger-Federer.csv')`. You don't have to move the file to open it from Python, though, you can just give it the entire file path, like `open('/home/emily/Downloads/Roger-Federer.csv')`, and that'll work just fine too.